# Android: How to control when to start/stop a sound in different fragment pages?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I have an activity that has a fragment with 18 pages. In some of the pages, there is a sound that can be played when the play button is clicked. However, when the user clicks on the play button and switches to another page, the sound from the previous page is still playing. How can make it play only in the relevant page, and stop if the page is switched?

```
public class PageFragment_Bon extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    private Button start, stop, replay;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int [] filer = new int[18];


    public static PageFragment_Bon newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment_Bon fragment = new PageFragment_Bon();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
           }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_boenner, container, false);

        start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);

        stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        replay = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.replay);
        replay.setOnClickListener(this);

        filer[2] = R.raw.Hello;
        filer[4] = R.raw.Welcome;
        filer[14] = R.raw.Intro;
        filer[15] = R.raw.Farewell;
        filer[16] = R.raw.Leave;

        if(filer[mPage] != 0){
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            replay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mediaPlayer == null)
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), filer[mPage]);
        if(v == start){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        else if(v == stop){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        else if(v == replay){
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by pages? are you using ViewPager?

Comment: I am using FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this inside your fragments that have sounds

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if(!isVisibleToUser){

        if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

By overriding `setUserVisibleHint` in your `Fragment`, you can determine when Fragment becomes visible

**Edit**

Start media player with try and catch (in case if there is any exception while you are trying to start media player)

```
   if(v == start){
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It stops the sound but when I return to the page and click on the start button it doesn't start anymore

Comment: @Mr.T Please check your log and see if there are any exceptions from catch block, And don't forget to start your media player with try and catch

Comment: Yes: java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.

Comment: @Mr.T I don't think that `Invalid device key response` has anything to do with media player, I've updated my answer, see logs if media player still doesn't start

Comment: it just says: `05-06 22:22:09.843 2435-2435/com.app.hudhud.myapp E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
05-06 22:22:09.843 2435-2435/com.app.hudhud.myapp E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
05-06 22:22:09.843 2435-2435/com.app.hudhud.myapp E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)`

Answer (score 0):

It is better to override onPause() and onResume() in fragment. And we need to save the current position for media player. So, I am using the shared preference to save the position for media player.
In onCreateView, 
mediaPlayer_position = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PLAY_PAUSE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("CHECK_PLAY_PAUSE", 0);

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   int position = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PLAY_PAUSE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("CHECK_PLAY_PAUSE", 0);
    if(position > 0) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3_link);//mp3_link from url to MediaPlayer data source
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer_position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PLAY_PAUSE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("CHECK_PLAY_PAUSE", mediaPlayer_position).apply();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

}
```

Ref: "https://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class"